# Ruby on Rails installation Error on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed ruby and rails by using rvm.

My ubuntu version is 12.04
ruby version is  ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
rails version is Rails 4.1.2
rvm version is rvm 1.25.27 (stable)

After installation i create a demo application with rails new demo
Now when i type rake about i am getting the below error

```
hadoopnode1@hadoopnode1:~/work/demo$ rake about

rake aborted!

ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.

/home/hadoopnode1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/execjs-2.2.1/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect'

/home/hadoopnode1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/execjs-2.2.1/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'

/home/hadoopnode1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/execjs-2.2.1/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'

/home/hadoopnode1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/uglifier-2.5.1/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'

/home/hadoopnode1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/uglifier-2.5.1/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'

/home/hadoopnode1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'

/home/hadoopnode1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'

/home/hadoopnode1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'

/home/hadoopnode1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'

/home/hadoopnode1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'

/home/hadoopnode1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'

/home/hadoopnode1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'

/home/hadoopnode1/work/demo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'

/home/hadoopnode1/work/demo/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Please help me on this..

Comment: You should indent the output with four spaces to make it appear in a code block

Answer (score 2):

You need a javascript runtime like nodejs

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a javascript runtime for some of the functionality in rails. ExecJS can use a few different runtimes, e.g. if Node.js is installed system wide this will work (see @Iceman's answer). If you can't install packages, then you can simply add the following to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Rails 3.1, a JavaScript runtime has been needed for development on Ubuntu Linux. The JavaScript runtime is required to compile code for the Rails asset pipeline. For development on Ubuntu Linux it is best to install the Node.js server-side JavaScript environment:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

and set it in your $PATH.

If you don’t install Node.js, you’ll need to add this to the Gemfile for each Rails application you build:

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

My article [Install Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu Linux](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html) offers additional guidance and advice for configuring your Rails development environment on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Using your editor of choice, open the Gemfile and look for this

## gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

delete the hash so your file looks like this:

gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

hit save and you should be good to go.